# i want to get average first response time based on question posted and answered time

Tags: php, mysql

table :- tb_addquestion

| QuestionId | Created_at |
| --- | --- |
| 122125 | 2021-07-21 09:01:25 |
| 122126 | 2021-07-21 09:13:43 |
| 122127 | 2021-07-21 14:17:07 |
| 122128 | 2021-07-21 19:53:19 |
| 122129 | 2021-07-21 20:04:09 |

table :- tb_answer

| id | Created_at | QuestionId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 165055 | 2021-07-21 10:29:45 | 122126 |
| 165056 | 2021-07-21 12:35:36 | 122124 |
| 165057 | 2021-07-21 15:17:04 | 122127 |
| 165058 | 2021-07-21 18:58:11 | 122125 |
| 165059 | 2021-07-21 20:02:14 | 122128 |
| 165060 | 2021-07-21 20:03:17 | 122128 |
| 165061 | 2021-07-21 20:03:29 | 122128 |
| 165062 | 2021-07-21 20:03:33 | 122128 |
| 165063 | 2021-07-21 20:04:08 | 122128 |
| 165064 | 2021-07-22 00:40:21 | 122129 |

i want to calculate the average response time of a day. now i am joining all the repeated answer response time too but i want to avoid that and take only the first answer inserted time corresponding the question. for example here questionid - 122128 have 5 answers in tb_answer table but i want the first posted answer only like wise for all the questions.

```
 $time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s ', time());
 $gmt = gmdate('Y-m-d', strtotime($time)) . " 00:00:00";

 $select_avgresponsetime = $mysqli->query("SELECT a.Created_at AS qtime,b.Created_at AS atime FROM tb_addquestion AS a INNER JOIN tb_answer b ON a.QuestionId=b.QuestionId WHERE a.Created_at  >='$gmt' OR b.Created_at  >='$gmt'");
 $a = 0;
 if (mysqli_num_rows($select_avgresponsetime) > 0) {
     while ($row_avgresTime = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_avgresponsetime)) {
         // print_r($row_avgresTime);
         $a++;
         $b = +$a;
         $qtime = date('H:i:s', (strtotime($row_avgresTime['qtime'])));
         $atime = date('H:i:s', (strtotime($row_avgresTime['atime'])));
         $qadiff_time = strtotime($atime) - strtotime($qtime);
         $qadiff_str = gmdate('H:i:s', $qadiff_time);
         $qdiff_total = $qdiff_total + $qadiff_time;
     }
     $qdiff_total_avg = $qdiff_total / $b;
     $avgResponseTime = gmdate('H:i:s', $qdiff_total_avg);
 } else {
     $avgResponseTime = 0;
 }
```

Comment: I have a lot of difficulties understanding what you are asking... you want the average of what? which table and which column?

Comment: average time of answer responded to  questions  for a day . here tb_addquestion is for posting questions and tb_answer is for posting answer. while posting a qtn and answering the qtn i generate created at timestamp. also we have the provion of reanswering the same qtn which also save in Tb_answer  as a new row . i want to exclude that reanswered time stamp

Comment: So you need to determine the lowest value within a group. Approaches on how to do that are shown under https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html (the other way around there, they are looking for a groupwise maximum, you want the minimum instead.)

Comment: @CBroe thanks for the reference i got the query

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with one MySQL query with something like that:

```
SELECT t.QuestionId, avg(t.diff) 
FROM (
    SELECT 
        tb_addquestion.QuestionId as QuestionId,
        TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(tb_answer.Created_at, tb_addquestion.Created_at)) as diff 
    FROM tb_answer 
    INNER JOIN tb_addquestion ON tb_answer.QuestionId = tb_addquestion.QuestionId
) as t 
GROUP BY t.QuestionId
```

Not tested, may contain some minor errors. But it should output you the average number of seconds per question.